# Как правильно сделать калькулятор стоимости

Tags: javascript, jquery, калькулятор

Делаю калькулятор стоимости, но у меня не получается. 
При смене значения в `select'e`, считается прошлое и новое значение, как правильно реализовать, чтобы все считало корректно?

*`mat_count`* - количество материала, элементы добавляются динамически, поэтому при добавлении каждого нового он увеличивается и создает в блоке элемент `select` c `selectIdMat + max_count`

```js
    var mat_count = 0;
var price_stone = 700;
var price_wood = 600;
var price_granite = 800;`введите сюда код`
var sum = 0;
$('#add_dblock').click(function() {
    mat_count++;
    var objTo = document.getElementById('fields')
    var divtest = document.createElement("div");
    divtest.innerHTML = '<div class="dblock"> <form action="" method="post" class="dblock_form"><select id="selectIdMat'+ mat_count +'"><option>Выберите материал</option><option>Дерево</option><option>Камень</option><option>Гранит</option></select></form></div>';
    objTo.appendChild(divtest);
$('#selectIdMat' + mat_count).on('change', function() {
  var selectMat = $('#selectIdMat' + mat_count + ' option:selected').val();
  switch (selectMat) {
    case 'Дерево':
      sum = sum + price_wood;
      $('#price').text(sum);
      break;
    case 'Камень':
      sum = sum + price_stone;
      $('#price').text(sum);
      break;
    case 'Гранит':
      sum = sum + price_granite;
      $('#price').text(sum);
      break;
  }
})})
```

```html
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="fields">
<button id="add_dblock">Добавить
</button>
</div>
<div id="price">0
</div>
```

Comment: для начала перестань писать `$('#price').text(sum);` в каждом кейсе.. Это не решение, но это называют "странным кодом"

Comment: @Nikolay, да, можно это делать вне switch, я знаю, но вопрос в другом

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Так как автор вопроса не написал, в чем заключается "неправильность" его кода, а пример в вопросе вообще не работает, я, как обычно, использовал мои телепатические способности.*

```
//var selectMat = $('#selectIdMat' + mat_count + ' option:selected').val();
var selectMat = $(this).val();
switch (selectMat) {
  ...
```

*Упражнение для читателя: объяснить, почему это является решением.*

---

```js
$(document).on('change', '.select-material', function() {
  var priceList = [
    { material: 'Дерево', price: 600 },
    { material: 'Камень', price: 700 },
    { material: 'Гранит', price: 800 }
  ];
  var sum = 0;
  $('.select-material').each(function(){
    var material = $(this).val();
    for (var i = 0; i < priceList.length; i++) {
      if (material == priceList[i].material) {
        sum = sum + priceList[i].price;
        break;
      }
    }
  });
  $('#price').text(sum);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Total: <span id="price"></span><br/>
<select class="select-material">
  <option>Выберите материал</option>
  <option>Дерево</option>
  <option>Камень</option>
  <option>Гранит</option>
</select>
<select class="select-material">
  <option>Выберите материал</option>
  <option>Дерево</option>
  <option>Камень</option>
  <option>Гранит</option>
</select>
```

Comment: _При смене значения в select'e, считается прошлое и новое значение_


Т.е. - дерево - 700, гранит - 900, если в одном поле поставить дерево и потом поменять на гранит, то покажет 1600, а не 900

Comment: @nameisusselesinfo А что Вы ожидали при `sum = sum + ...;`? Сделайте работающий пример в вопросе.

Comment: я оставлял фрагмент кода, работающий пример не делал, подумал в этом можно найти ошибку, потому что в полном коде будет много лишнего, то же создание динамических блоков

Comment: код отредактировал, чтобы было понятнее. Попробуйте выбрать "Гранит", а потом "Камень" и увидите в чем у меня проблема, они суммировались, вместо того, чтобы суммировать значение последнего

Answer (score 0):

если я правильно понял вопрос, то тебе необходим буфер, где ты будешь хранить текущее значение. Таковым может выступать, к примеру, `data` атрибут. [Описание работы с методом](https://api.jquery.com/data/). При изменении `select` ты просто будет брать значение из `data` атрибута и складывать его с деревом или гранитом. Дефолтное значение может быть 0.

Comment: Отредактировал код, проблема в том, что если я добавлю select, выберу в нем значение и еще раз его поменяю у меня суммируется новое его значение и прошлое, а требуется только последнее